# Client side warning (6:29521)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, warnings, react-bootstrap, autoprefixer

I am working on a React project. I use ReactBootstrap on my project. Whenever I run the project using npm start the terminal shows the warning:

WARNING in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(6:29521) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please use search first. This question has been asked ten times at least.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A GitHubber [fixed this problem by running this command](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36259):

```bash
npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact
```

Comment: I am following an Angular course and had the similar warning when i implemented bootstrap into my project. I used `npm install -g autoprefixer@latest` and did not have the same warning again. Thank you for the information.